# Proof of Equality of Null Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let ${\bf A}, {\bf B} \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be a pair of matrices such that:
$$
{\rm Null}\left({\bf A}\right) \subseteq {\rm Null}\left({\bf B}\right)
$$
Furthermore, it is known that the null spaces of both $\bf A$ and $\bf B$ have the same dimension.

Is it true then that ${\rm Null}\left({\bf A}\right) = {\rm Null}\left({\bf B}\right)$? If so, how can it be proven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more general question is "if $W$ is a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ and $\dim W = \dim V$, does this imply $W=V$?"

This is true: take a basis for $W$. It is a linearly independent set in $V$ with the same cardinality as the dimension of $V$, so it is also a basis for $V$.

Comment: I beg to differ, I could have $(0,1)$ as a basis for $W$ and $(1,0)$ as a basis for $V$; then ${\rm dim} W = {\rm dim} V$ but clearly $W \ne V$

Comment: @DanielTurizo Your example does not satisfy $W$ being a subspace of $V$.

Comment: You are right, please excuse me.